# Как правильно написать setup.py для копирования dll?

Tags: c, python-3.x

Есть две linux библиотеки с файл для работы с ними написанный на с. Ко всему этому есть следующий setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension("ValueCalculate", 
                   sources = ["value_calculate/binding.cpp"],)
                   library_dirs=['value_calculate'],
                   libraries=['ValueCalculate', 'swe'])


setup(name="ValueCalculate",
      version="1.0",
      description="",
      ext_modules = [module,],
      packages=['value_calculate'],
      package_data={'value_calculate': ['libValueCalculate.so','libswe.so']}
      )
```

После выполнения установки и импорте пакета получаю ошибку о том что не найдена библиотека `libValueCalculate.so`. Как надо исправить setup.py что бы он копировал библиотеки куда надо?

Comment: `.cpp` намекает на C++, а не Си.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Install mixture of extension module. pure python module and shared libraries with distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6945969/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Установку Си зависимостей, которые не имеют отношения к Питону, лучше оставить таким инструментам как системные менеджеры пакетов. Если Сишная библиотека тесно связана с вашим Питон кодом, то лучше её из исходников собирать.

Но если вы всё-таки хотите распространять простые .dll/.so файлы, которые не являются расширениями для Питона (не определяют Питон модули), то `package_data` это уже делает. К примеру, пакет:

```
.
├── non_extension_dll
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── dlls
│       └── libfunc.so
└── setup.py
```

и соответствующий `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='non-extension-dll',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['non_extension_dll'],
    package_data={'non_extension_dll': ['dlls/*.so']})
```

тогда установка пакета также устанавливает и файлы из dlls папки:

```
$ pip install non-extension-dll
```

Если ваш пакет установлен в `site-packages` директорию, то после установки вы сможете найти: `site-packages/non_extension_dll/dlls/libfunc.so` файл.

Для теста, можно добавить `__main__.py` скрипт, который использует эту библиотеку:

```
.
├── non_extension_dll
│   ├── __main__.py
```

с кодом:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes
import os

sopath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dlls', 'libfunc.so')
lib = ctypes.CDLL(sopath)
lib.func()  # assuming the func library defines func() function
```

Это загружает библиотеку и вызывает функцию из неё.

Comment: Сделал всё как вы сказали. Ошибка при импорте undefined symbol. Проверил с помощью nm. Всё есть. Почему он не видит функцию?

Comment: @Andru: про "undefined symbol" лучше отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задать. Попробуйте создать с нуля минимальный пример (как у меня в ответе: одна функция без аргументов, которая внутри, к примеру, просто `printf("hello world\n");`  вызывает). Соберите so файл (если не знаете как, спросите). Попробуйте его сразу же использовать без установки (запустите python в той же директории и попробуйте вызвать функцию, используя ctypes (если из модуля, то можно код из ответа с ctypes использовать). [mcve]

Comment: Это уже всё делал. Целых два дня с проблемой борюсь. Хотя тз сделать биндинг к библиотеке которая уже собрана. Вот осталось совсем чучуть.

Comment: @Andru "всё сделал" — где результат?